# por que en este código TKinter no puede volver una variable de sting a float para usarlo con math

Tags: python, tkinter, math

Estoy intentando hacer una calculadora de ley de coseno, pero no logro pasar la entrada de `str` a `float`.

```
import tkinter as tk
import math

ventana = tk.Tk()
ventana.title("ley de seno")
ventana.geometry('720x480')
ventana.configure(background='dark turquoise')
var = tk.StringVar()

def lados():
    lados = math.sqrt((math.pow(float(entrada1.get()), 2) + math.pow(float(entrada2.get()), 2)) - (
            2 * (float(entrada1.get())) * (float(entrada2.get())) * (math.cos(float(entrada3.get())))))

    return var.set(lados)

e1 = tk.Label(ventana, text='Numero 1:', bg='pink', fg='white')
e1.pack(padx=5, pady=4, ipadx=5, ipady=4, fill=tk.X)
entrada1 = tk.Entry(ventana)
entrada1.pack(fill=tk.X, padx=5, pady=5, ipadx=5, ipady=5, )

e2 = tk.Label(ventana, text='Numero 2:', bg='pink', fg='white')
e2.pack(padx=5, pady=4, ipadx=5, ipady=4, fill=tk.X)
entrada2 = tk.Entry(ventana)
entrada2.pack(fill=tk.X, padx=5, pady=5, ipadx=5, ipady=5, )

e3 = tk.Label(ventana, text='Numero 3:', bg='pink', fg='white')
e3.pack(padx=5, pady=4, ipadx=5, ipady=4, fill=tk.X)
entrada3 = tk.Entry(ventana)
entrada3.pack(fill=tk.X, padx=5, pady=5, ipadx=5, ipady=5, )

lado = tk.Button(ventana, text='lado',comand=lados())
lado.pack()
angulo = tk.Button(ventana, text='angulo')
angulo.pack()

eresul1 = tk.Label(ventana, textvariable=var, bg='pink', fg='white')
eresul1.pack(fill=tk.X, padx=5, pady=5, ipadx=5, ipady=5)

ventana.mainloop()
```

Cuando corro el programa me da este error y no entiendo que estoy haciendo mal

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: ''
```

Si alguien sabe que está ocurriendo agradecería que me lo dijera, por que apenas estoy empezando y este es mi primer gran proyecto, y estoy muy frustrado.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que la función `lados()` se está ejecutando justo al iniciar el script. Esto ya que al argumento `command` del `Button` llamado `lado` se le asigna la función directamente. La función no se ejecuta cuando se presiona el botón, si no al iniciar el script.

> Cuando corro el programa me da este error y no entiendo que estoy haciendo mal

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: ''
```

Dicho lo anterior, el valor que retorna el método `get()` de cualquier entrada va a ser un string vació o `''`. La función al ejecutarse al iniciar el programa, no hay manera de ingrear un valor al `Entry`, por esto mismo se obtiene una cadena vacía.

### ¿Cómo solucionarlo?

> Si alguien sabe que está ocurriendo agradecería que me lo dijera

Hay otras manera, pero la más fácil es ejecutando la función dentro de una función lambda (una función anónima).

```
boton = tk.Button(ventana,text="Ejecutar función",command = lambda: lados())
```

Por cierto, te recomiendo guardar este valor en una `DoubleVar`, luego es más fácil usar el valor para hacer operaciones matemáticas.

Espero te haya servido de algo.

Comment: De paso, el OP debe revisar porque tiene `comand` con una sola m.

Answer (score 0):

Aquí hay varios errores:

La propiedad `command` debe contener el nombre de la función y no la ejecución de esta. Es decir: `command=lado` en lugar de `command=lado()`.

Lo recomendable es que todos los `Entry`tengan asociado un `textvariable` para poder tener control de los datos de forma organizada. Así tendrías

```
v_num1 = StringVar()
v_num2 = StringVar()
v_num3 = StringVar()
```

Entonces los asignas a cada uno de los `Entry`.

Ahora la razón de tu error: buscando la ayuda de un `Entry` no veo que tenga el método `get` de la forma widget.get(), que es como lo estas llamando en la función. La forma de obtener el contenido de un `Entry` es utilizando el `textvariable` asociado, es decir, `v_num.get()`

Realiza esos cambios y el programa funcionará.

Comment: Esto es falso, puedes acceder al valor ingresado en un Entry con el método `.get()`. No es necesario que se haya definido un `StringVar()` anteriormente.

Comment: Es cierto! Siempre se aprende algo nuevo. Gracias.